# $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I just started learning angularjs, and run into this problem. The above error occurs when I run the application. 
My codes are as follows

app.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('underscore', []).factory('_', function () {
return window._;
});

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/a',
    {
        controller: 'aController',
        templateUrl: 'module/a/a.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
});
```

a.js (controller)

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('aController',
function($scope,aCollection, $location) {
    $scope.foo= {

    };

    $scope.create= function() {
        aCollection.create($scope.foo);
        $location.path('/a-creation');
    };
});
```

aCollection.js (service)

```
'use strict';

myApp.factory('aCollection', function($resource) {
return $resource('../api/dummy', {}, {
    create : {method: 'POST' }
})
});
```

The error is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20aCollection
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:6:417
at http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:38:7
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:36:13)
at http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:38:81
at d (http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:36:13)
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:36:283)
at Object.$get (http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:34:268)
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:36:315)
at http://localhost:9080/lib/angular.min.js:38:110 <div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Can someone help me out with this?? Many Thanks!!!

Comment: can you provide the *full* error? or at least the part that says which provider is the one that failed?

Comment: sorry about it. I've attached the full error.

Comment: problem is fixed. it is the issue with version conflict between angular.js and angular-route.js

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('aController', ['$scope', 'aCollection', '$location', function($scope, aCollection, $location) {
    $scope.foo= {

    };

    $scope.create= function() {
        aCollection.create($scope.foo);
        $location.path('/a-creation');
    };
}]).factory('aCollection', function($resource) {
      return $resource('../api/dummy', {}, {
           create : {method: 'POST' }
      })
});
```

**EDITED**

Comment: it is still the same error. and I actually separate the controller and service to maintain a better structure of files

Comment: Wait I'll try to fix my code.

Just a question, if you seperated those 2 javascript files, how will you know that the Factory was called?

Comment: it is actually able to call the factory